# unable to produce data using entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have Sale table and payment table i am able retrieve data using below sql but same result unable to produce using entity framework

```
select m.id,Sum(p.PaymentAmount),
 InvoiceAmount FROM Sale m
 Left Join Payment p on m.id =p.saleid
 Where m.DueDate < getdate() 
 Group by m.id,InvoiceAmount
 having ISNULL(Sum(p.PaymentAmount),0) < InvoiceAmount
```

I have return Query for same but it doen`t work

```
_salesRepository
    .GetAll()
    .Where(m => m.DueDate < DateTime.Now && m.Payment.GroupBy(o => o.SaleID).Select(g => new { TotalSale = g.Sum(i => i.PaymentAmount) }).Any(g => g.TotalSale < m.InvoiceAmount))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var getdate = DateTime.Now;

var data = (from s in _salesRepository.GetAll()
           join p in _paymentsRepository.GetAll() 
           on s.id == p.saleid into subPs
           from subP in subPs.DefaultIfEmpty()
           where s.DueDate < getdate
           group new { s, subP } by new { s.id, s.InvoiceAmount } into leftSub
           let PaymentAmount = leftSub.Sum(x => x.subP == null ? 0 : x.subP.PaymentAmount)
           where PaymentAmount < leftSub.Key.InvoiceAmount
           select new { 
               leftSub.Key.id,
               PaymentAmount,
               leftSub.Key.InvoiceAmount 
           }).ToList();
```